# c# dynamic query string Issue

Tags: c#, salesforce, soql

I want to save a query as a string with "variable-name" in a file as -

```
SELECT Id FROM Object WHERE name = "+ VARIABLE_NAME + "
```

and want to execute query like -

```
public void executeQuery(String VARIABLE_NAME)
 {
   String query = ReadQuery(); // some method which reads queryfrom file.

   ExecuteQuery(query );   // value of VARIABLE_NAME should be included from parameter  

  }
```

I want to variable Value should be included from parameter. I can not use it like this -

> command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VARIABLE_NAME", VARIABLE_NAME);

Please provide me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

**Note : This is SOQL query, not SQL query.**

Comment: please read how to use sqlplarameter, http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: "*I can not use it like this "* why?

Comment: @YuliamChandra - this is not simple sql query. this is soql query so we can not use it like  that. Thanks.

Comment: create stored procedure and pass parameter straight. Do handling on SQL side

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem was not surrounding the parameter string with ' '.

```
SOQL = "select x, y, z from Document where y='" + SOME_PARAMETER + "';";
```

However, this is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: This is SOQL query, Not simple SQL query.

Comment: So are you looking for an alternative to prevent SQL injection using the custom classes of SOQL?

Comment: SOQL is "Salesforce object query language" to get data from salesforce. It is slightly different from SQL.

Comment: I just want to build dynamic query for SOQL.